# Flutter update Reorderable ListView when checkbox in AlertDialog check or unchecked

Tags: android, ios, listview, flutter, dart

I'm currently working on a Flutter mobile app which is supposed to work on Android and IOS.
The issue I'm having is about ListView and updating it.

I know I'm doing wrong with a lot of things but I'm learning and I would like to learn properly. So if you have any comments, tips about the code pls give them :)

Basically here is what it does : 
The main player will choose who will play with him at the game via an AlertDialog which has a CheckboxList inside it and every time he selects a player, it will update a list called choosenPlayers which has all Player objects choosen in it.

Then what I want to do is to display a list of all selected players (a reorderable list to change the order of players) and update it everytime the choosenPlayers list is updated.

I managed to display these players but I have to reload the page by going in the drawer menu and clicking on page link to see added players.

I use a stateful widget for my players reorderable list and I pass to the parent the list of players (This is not the rigth way to do it I know) :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mollky/models/player.dart';

class ChoosenPlayers extends StatefulWidget {
  _ChoosenPlayersState _choosenPlayersState = _ChoosenPlayersState();
  List<Player> choosenPlayers = [];
  ChoosenPlayers({Key key, this.choosenPlayers}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChoosenPlayersState createState() => _choosenPlayersState;
}

class _ChoosenPlayersState extends State<ChoosenPlayers> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      onReorder: onReorder,
      children: getListItems(),
    );
  }

  List<ListTile> getListItems() => widget.choosenPlayers
      .asMap()
      .map((i, item) => MapEntry(i, buildTenableListTile(item, i)))
      .values
      .toList();

  ListTile buildTenableListTile(Player item, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      key: ValueKey(item.id),
      title: Text(item.nickname + " " + item.name),
      leading: Text("#${index + 1}"),
    );
  }

  void onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
      newIndex -= 1;
    }

    setState(() {
      Player reOrderedPlayer = widget.choosenPlayers[oldIndex];

      widget.choosenPlayers.removeAt(oldIndex);
      widget.choosenPlayers.insert(newIndex, reOrderedPlayer);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the code of the main page where reorderable list is displayed and AlertDialog showed.
Sorry, couldn't format with Dart, don't run the code snipped obviously xD

```Dart
class NewGame extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => NewGameState();
}

class NewGameState extends State<NewGame> {
  List<Player> players = [];

  NewGameState() {
    this.players.add(
        Player(id: 0, name: "Dupont", nickname: "julien", picture: "test"));
    this
        .players
        .add(Player(id: 1, name: "Dpont", nickname: "julien", picture: "test"));
    this
        .players
        .add(Player(id: 2, name: "Dunt", nickname: "juen", picture: "test"));
  }

  static List<Player> _choosenPlayers = [];
  ChoosenPlayers choosenPlayersObject = ChoosenPlayers(
    choosenPlayers: _choosenPlayers,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: DrawerWidget(),
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Nouvelle partie")),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Card(
              child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.people),
                  title: Text("Choisissez les joueurs"),
                  onTap: () {
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                              title: Text("Les joueurs existants"),
                              content:
                                  Stack(overflow: Overflow.visible, children: <
                                      Widget>[
                                Positioned(
                                  right: -40.0,
                                  top: -40.0,
                                  child: InkResponse(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      child: Icon(Icons.close),
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Positioned(
                                  child: StatefulBuilder(
                                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                                        StateSetter setState) {
                                      return Container(
                                        width: 350.0,
                                        height: 150.0,
                                        child: ListView.builder(
                                            itemCount: players.length,
                                            itemBuilder:
                                                (context, playerIndex) {
                                              return CheckboxListTile(
                                                title: Text(players[playerIndex]
                                                        .nickname +
                                                    " " +
                                                    players[playerIndex].name),
                                                value: _choosenPlayers.contains(
                                                    players[playerIndex]),
                                                onChanged: (bool value) {
                                                  if (!_choosenPlayers.contains(
                                                      players[playerIndex])) {
                                                    _choosenPlayers.add(
                                                        players[playerIndex]);
                                                    setState(() {});
                                                  } else {
                                                    _choosenPlayers.remove(
                                                        players[playerIndex]);
                                                    setState(() {});
                                                  }
                                                },
                                                secondary: const Icon(
                                                    Icons.hourglass_empty),
                                              );
                                            }),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]));
                        });
                  })),
          Container(
            width: 350.0,
            height: 150.0,
            child: choosenPlayersObject,
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

I've seen nothing on forums about updating list without triggering a callback like onRefresh which is not what I want.

It is a real nightmare xD. Sorry for french words btw I can translate if needed but they are not important, simple text.

Here are two screenshots of the list and alert dialog :

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **state** of parent widget is not updated. That's why, even though the payer is added to the list. But not shown to in parent widget.
The **setState** you called only update the state of **StatefulBuilder** not of the **NewGame**.
Check out the below code.

[image: demo]

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: NewGameScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class NewGameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewGameScreenState createState() => _NewGameScreenState();
}

class _NewGameScreenState extends State<NewGameScreen> {
  List<Player> _availablePlayers = [];
  List<Player> _selectedPlayers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _availablePlayers = [
      Player(id: 0, name: "Ross", nickname: "Geller", picture: "test"),
      Player(id: 1, name: "Rachel", nickname: "Green", picture: "test"),
      Player(id: 2, name: "Chandler", nickname: "Bing", picture: "test"),
    ];
  }

  _selectPlayer() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Existing players"),
          content: Stack(
            overflow: Overflow.visible,
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                right: -40.0,
                top: -40.0,
                child: InkResponse(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    child: Icon(Icons.close),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter alertState) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 350.0,
                    height: 150.0,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _availablePlayers.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, playerIndex) {
                        return CheckboxListTile(
                          title:
                              Text(_availablePlayers[playerIndex].nickname + " " + _availablePlayers[playerIndex].name),
                          value: _selectedPlayers.contains(_availablePlayers[playerIndex]),
                          onChanged: (bool value) {
                            if (_selectedPlayers.contains(_availablePlayers[playerIndex])) {
                              _selectedPlayers.remove(_availablePlayers[playerIndex]);
                            } else {
                              _selectedPlayers.add(_availablePlayers[playerIndex]);
                            }
                            setState(() {});//ALSO UPDATE THE PARENT STATE
                            alertState(() {});
                          },
                          secondary: const Icon(Icons.hourglass_empty),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
      newIndex -= 1;
    }
    print('oldIndex:$oldIndex');
    print('newIndex:$newIndex');
    setState(() {
      Player player = _selectedPlayers[newIndex];
      _selectedPlayers[newIndex] = _selectedPlayers[oldIndex];
      _selectedPlayers[oldIndex] = player;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("New Game")),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.people),
              title: Text("Choose players"),
              onTap: _selectPlayer,
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: ReorderableListView(
              onReorder: _onReorder,
              children: _selectedPlayers.map((player) {
                return ListTile(
                  key: ValueKey(player.id),
                  title: Text(player.nickname + " " + player.name),
                  leading: Text("#${_selectedPlayers.indexOf(player) + 1}"),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Player {
  int id;
  String name;
  String nickname;
  String picture;

  Player({this.id, this.name, this.nickname, this.picture});
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you !!! You saved me hours of troubles ! And thank you for using proper naming for variables, classes and methods ! I hope your answer will help others !